# Mi pregunta ha sido considerada como demasiado amplia y corre el riesgo de ser cerrada

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

De nuevo por aquí para pedir sus orientaciones...

Llevo poco tiempo en SO. Me lancé hace poco en la aventura de una pregunta-respuesta que corrió el riesgo de ser cerrada. Al final no fue así, gracias a Dios.

Hoy quise preguntar sobre la nueva versión de la librería jQuery, o sea la versión 3, con la finalidad de tener a mano algo básico sobre las principales novedades de la misma, sobre como implementarla, etc.

La pregunta corre el riesgo de ser cerrada, al ser considerada demasiado amplia.

La respuesta sería amplia en cuanto al contenido, ya que jQuery 3 trae novedades importantes... pero no en cuanto a lo que se pregunta. Yo entendía por *demasiado amplia* una pregunta tan abierta a la que varias personas puedan responder de diversa forma sin llegar a un consenso. Pero aquí es muy preciso lo que estoy preguntando:

> ¿Cuáles son las principales novedades de jQuery 3?
>
> ¿Cuáles son las principales ventajas de esta librería con respecto a
>   las versiones 1 y 2?
>
> ¿Qué hacer para empezar a usarla?

Es la segunda vez que formulo preguntas de este tipo y veo que son de alguna manera ¿obstaculizadas?. Se ve que no he entendido del todo bien la forma de funcionar de SO.

[Este es el enlace original de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51533/29967). Agradezco sus opiniones y sugerencias.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Somos demasiados exigentes con las preguntas de los usuarios?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466/somos-demasiados-exigentes-con-las-preguntas-de-los-usuarios).

Comment: Existe una diferencia entre amplia (muchas soluciones posibles, califica para cierre) y extensa (la respuesta es muy larga, no califica para cierre). Justo como lo puse en el comentario de la pregunta, no estoy seguro que sea demasiado amplia, sino que la respuesta será extensa, son preguntas directas respecto a la librería jQuery, cuenta con mi voto para reapertura (*la pregunta ha sido reabierta*).

Comment: @Flxtr yo no entiendo "demasiado amplia" significando "muchas soluciones posibles". Según la definición, demasiado amplia para mi se refiere a preguntas que requieren respuestas que necesariamente tienen que ser tan extenso que no cuadran en este sitio. Viendo que hay respuestas bien largas que son bien recibidos en SO, eso se debe referir a "proyectos enteros" o algo parecido.

Comment: @StefanNolde acorde a la definición de [es.so] ambos estamos en lo correcto: *Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato.*

Comment: Ok, pero hay una diferencia étnica en el sentido de la palabra "mucho". En ingles parece que "mucho" empieza en los dos dígitos, en español parece más como "más que uno o dos". Eso depende del grado de desarrollo que tiene un país?

Comment: @sstan Gracias por el enlace. Comparto tu opinión en lo que allí dices. He hecho apenas dos publicaciones de este tipo y antes de las dos horas, sin siquiera haber respuestas, había 3 ó 4 personas pidiendo que la pregunta sea cerrada. Tal actitud, creo, empobrecerá a esSO, más aún considerando que el contenido en español es muy pobre comparado con contenido en inglés, en francés y en otros idiomas.

Comment: Gracias @Flxtr . Creo que este tipo de preguntas contribuyen a enriquecer la documentación en español de librerías tan usadas y cuyo contenido existe básicamente en inglés. Cuando sale algo nuevo pasan meses y a veces hasta años para tener documentación importante en castellano. Saludos.

Comment: Me parece que respuestas para este tipo de preguntas lucen más como entradas de blog que como preguntas específicas para este sitio. En mi opinión, es demasiado amplia.

Comment: Yo he visto en SOen, preguntas de ese tipo y son contestadas e incluso tienen votos a favor, yo mismo he hecho preguntas en inglés de este tipo y siempre me han contestado. ¿Será que por esto estamos detrás de lo que es los programadores en inglés? Porque no damos ese extra y nos limitamos a simplemente cerrar una pregunta que podría ayudar al OP y a muchas personas más que tienen la misma duda. Ya se que SO no es un sustituto de Google, pero tal vez al buscar en Google te salga la respuesta de SO (Sí la pregunta en vez de ser cerrada, fuera contestada).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Es una pregunta valida y de calidad *des de mi punto de vista subjetivo*.**

---

Dice Ruben en su [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1480/7242):

> Mi conclusión es que la pregunta no es un caso representativo de las preguntas que se espera tener en el sitio, pero pareciera ser un caso de excepción, por lo que no tengo inconveniente en que siga abierta, sin embargo, no debería usarse como justificación para que proliferen frecuentemente preguntas similares.

Y efectivamente tiene razón. Esta pregunta no es representativa de la mayoría de preguntas del sitio y por eso ha causado dudas.

La pregunta es concreta sobre una nueva versión especifica que busca resolver **3** dudas especificas.

Vamos a analizar el *posible* motivo de cierre por 'demasiado amplia':

> Existen muchas respuestas posibles

Falso. Solo hay una respuesta posible y si existe mas de una sera por poner mas detalles pero no se puede ser subjetivo en una respuesta a esta pregunta.

> o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato.

Aquí es donde me imagino que ha surgido la duda. Voy a compartir una respuesta del SO original, [How long of an answer is “too long for this format”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291716/1468942)

Donde se explica que demasiado extenso es algo subjetivo y como tal lo que comentan en el enlace que he compartido es que va enfocado a preguntas que son **extremadamente** largas por su planteamiento y que son de baja calidad.

En tu caso es una pregunta concreta que aunque contenga una respuesta extensa no lo es tanto.

Answer (score 4):

La [pregunta en cuestión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51533/29967) al momento tiene

- [14 eventos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/51533/timeline)
- 6 votos positivos
- ningún voto negativo
- Dos revisiones
- 5 comentarios
- 1 respuesta, la cual tiene

  - 4 votos positivos
  - 1 voto negativo
  - 6 comentarios
  - 2 revisiones

En lo que se respecta a su contenido
- Incluye tres preguntas
    - Una de ellas, podría decirse que solicita un recurso externo, la lista de novedades
    - Dos de ellas solicitan opiniones 
       - Una pregunta sobre las ventajas,
       - Otra sobre cómo empezar
Independiente a lo anterior,

Por lo anterior

1. Considero que la pregunta es demasiado amplia por incluir tres preguntas
2. Basada en opiniones por incluir dos preguntas son basadas en opiniones
3. Es de interés para la comunidad, ya que la pregunta y respuesta tienen balances positivos

Mi conclusión es que la pregunta no es un caso representativo de las preguntas que se espera tener en el sitio, pero pareciera ser un caso de excepción, por lo que no tengo inconveniente en que siga abierta, sin embargo, no debería usarse como justificación para que proliferen frecuentemente preguntas similares.