# Otro ejemplo típico del espíritu restrictivo en esSO

Tags: discusión

En más de una ocasión se ha hablado aquí de la actitud restrictiva de algunos en esSO.

Respeto la opinión de cada uno, pero creo que actitudes como estas sólo contribuyen a empobrecer el contenido de esta comunidad en su versión en castellano.

En este caso la pregunta del usuario es esta:

[¿Cómo usar una MySql en un programa de Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53103/c%C3%B3mo-usar-una-mysql-en-un-programa-de-java)

Veamos **exactamente la misma pregunta en enSO**:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database

Mientras en enSO la popularidad y utilidad de exactamente la misma pregunta es notable, en esSO corre el riesgo de desaparecer.

Me parece un contrasentido, mucho más si consideramos la poca existencia de documentación en castellano en lo que respecta a la informática.

He votado porque la pregunta se quede abierta y he comentado lo siguiente en la misma:

*He votado para que esta pregunta se deje abierta. 


1º porque se trata de un usuario reciente en esSO, 

2º porque es una pregunta que puede dar lugar a una respuesta interesante, rica que más de un usuario necesitará, 

3º porque preguntas similares han tenido muy buena aceptación en enSO: Veamos exactamente la misma pregunta en enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database


Ya comenté en el meta que cerrar este tipo de preguntas empobrecen el contenido de esSO: [Mi pregunta ha sido considerada como demasiado amplia y corre el riesgo de ser cerrada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1470/mi-pregunta-ha-sido-considerada-como-demasiado-amplia-y-corre-el-riesgo-de-ser-c)*

Comment: Cuidado. La pregunta que indicas en SOen es del año 2010, cuando SOen todavía no era tan restrictivo. Una pregunta similar ahora estaría cerrada y muy posiblemente eliminada por el sistema (si no es por los mismos usuarios).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La pregunta es útil, así lo muestra la aceptación que ha tenido en enSO. Que hoy tal pregunta podría ser cerrada ¿es opinión tuya o lo dice explícitamente en algún lado?

Comment: En realidad, en algún momento se discutió este tema en Meta SOen. Tendría que buscar las preguntas que hay respecto a esto. No lo digo yo. Inclusive, dentro de ese marco, la comunidad apuntó a borrar respuestas de Jon Skeet que eran malas (que sea el 1ro no hace que sea un súper usuario, sigue siendo un usuario más en la comunidad, lo mismo con cualquier publicación en ella).

Comment: En lo personal, todavía estoy tratando de captar el pulso de esta comunidad en cuanto a este tipo de preguntas. Hay veces que prefiero no contestar, sobre todo porque la pregunta no refleja ningún esfuerzo de investigación, como es el caso aquí. Pero hay veces que le doy mas peso a las razones que precisamente expusistes. Reconozco que que me falta coherencia :)

Answer (score 5):

Bueno, como yo comenté esa pregunta, quiero que consideren lo siguiente:

Estoy absolutamente de acuerdo con la opinión de [Stann](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1535/otro-ejemplo-t%C3%ADpico-del-esp%C3%ADritu-restrictivo-en-esso#comment4304_1535):

> ...Hay veces que prefiero no contestar, sobre todo porque la pregunta no refleja ningún esfuerzo de investigación...

y he demostrado esto con mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53103/c%C3%B3mo-usar-una-mysql-en-un-programa-de-java#comment94287_53103)

> Una respuesta a esta pregunta puede ser demasiado amplia y subjetiva. Te recomiendo que busques en internet tutoriales sobre como hacer la conexión. Cuando tengas alguna pregunta mas concreta , problema, error o situación particular ten toda la libertad de compartirla aquí, mientras tanto, es bastante probable que esta pregunta sea cerrada por ser demasiado amplia :(

En mi comentario agregué el siguiente [link a google](https://www.google.cl/search?q=conectar%20java%20mysql). Si le dan click al link, hay muchos blogs y post que muestran el proceso de conexión para la pregunta. Por lo tanto creo que esto es absolutamente falso para el caso de esta pregunta:

> Me parece un contrasentido, mucho más si consideramos la poca existencia de documentación en castellano en lo que respecta a la informática.

Si bien es cierto que voté para que cerraran la pregunta, también creo ciertamente que si la pregunta fue nominada a reapertura y posteriormente reabierta, es por que hay usuarios con buen juicio en esta comunidad que creen que la pregunta debe ser respondida y debe estar abierta. Entonces si A. Cedano abogaba por la pregunta, hizo bien en responderla dando honor a las [reglas de comportamiento básicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Por lo tanto ya no necesito volver a votar para que la pregunta sea cerrada.

Ahora, es cierto que [casi] nadie de los usuarios nuevos lee el articulo [COMO PREGUNTAR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), de hecho el usuario no tiene la medalla informado [Link a Bagdes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31754/sinxeros?tab=badges)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces pasa que las preguntas que estos usuarios "NO INFORMADOS" caben absolutamente en los malos ejemplos del link sobre como preguntar. Entonces estoy **absolutamente en desacuerdo** con esto:

> Otro ejemplo típico del espíritu restrictivo en esSO

Estoy seguro de que las normas de la comunidad la encaminan por la calidad. **No es espíritu restrictivo**, son recomendaciones y normas que nosotros mismos nos proponemos cumplir (Normas que acepté cuando me uní al sitio). De lo contrario pronto nos encontraríamos con otro Yahoo respuestas, dejando por el suelo lo que dice la [página de tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Somos ligeramente diferentes de otros sitios.

y también se representa en la página del [Beta Privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta):

> Estas preguntas no proveen contenido deseable para un beta privado porque no reflejan el tipo de preguntas que queremos almacenar aquí. No representan el estándar de calidad que deseamos tener como comunidad.

Con esto no digo que la pregunta no sea de calidad, sino que para responder una pregunta también se requiere una respuesta de calidad. Una respuesta de calidad para una pregunta tan amplia requiere tiempo, conocimientos específicos y varias "paginas" en la respuesta. Ahora cerrar la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia deja al usuario con al menos 2 opciones:

- Que investigue por si solo.
- Que divida la pregunta en preguntas especificas.

Esto quiere decir que si hace preguntas especificas aumenta la calidad del sitio y las posibilidades de que tenga una respuesta. Pero también es cierto que si la pregunta no es cerrada o es reabierta, por respeto a quien pregunta debe ser respondida por lo menos con un [mínimo de calidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Entonces muchas veces me encuentro con preguntas bastante extensas ([como esta que respondí hace poco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52817/c%C3%B3mo-usar-git-en-android-studio-mediante-ssh-con-claves-privadas)) y no siempre tengo el tiempo para dar una respuesta de calidad. Cuando considero que la respuesta es demasiada "extensa" para un usuario promedio, voto para cerrarla. Aun así siempre tengo presente que hay usuarios que están dispuestos a responder.

A pesar de todo esto, es normal que existan discusiones sobre estos temas. Después de todo la "comunidad" hace a StackOverflow. Aun así me gustaría saber quienes son la [comunidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) :P (Eso es un chiste)

Answer (score 2):

Yo sólo diré que:

1. El que desea ayudar, simplemente ayuda. "**Sin estar tirando golpes y rudeza**"
2. Hay usuarios que ni leen los reportes realizados a una pregunta, parecen polillas siguiendo una luz cuando ven que ésta se enciende. Sólo reportan porque hay otros que reportaron.
3. Los usuarios de StackOverflow inglés suelen ayudar mucho más sin recurrir a "necesitar" código trabajado. Sin quitar que en StackOverflow español hay muy buenos usuarios que en realidad se preocupan por el sitio, y indican con paciencia y calma a los nuevos o los que no saben cómo empezar a trabajar con algún lenguaje de programación en un tema específico.
4. Hay algunos usuarios que sólo dan downvotes, porque simplemente le molesta el usuario que pregunta, entre otras razones **personales**.
5. El cierre a una pregunta hecha por un usuario nuevo que no tiene idea de como empezar pero tiene el mérito es tolerado "**maltrato**" por parte de las políticas de StackOverflow.

Comment: El punto #1 es _en mi opinión_ el mas válido.

Answer (score 0):

Como le digo a mi hijo: de tus padres toma sólo *lo bueno*; *lo malo* ignóralo, perdónalo, pero sobre todo **no lo repitas**.

Ambas preguntas en inglés y en español no siguen los lineamientos sobre cómo preguntar. Una diferencia notable son las circunstancias de cada una, por ejemplo, la pregunta en inglés es del 2010 mientras que la pregunta en español es de hace 8 horas.

Mas que la pregunta en sí, a mí preocupa el trato al usuario. Si se ha de cerrar la pregunta, hay que cerrarla **amablemente** de tal forma que el usuario, si bien podría optar por abandonar la pregunta en cuestión, en primer lugar que se quede con un buen sabor de boca de esta comunidad y en segundo **que vuelva con buenas preguntas y respuestas**

Por otro lado, si te interesa el tema de la pregunta, publica una muy buena respuesta, y si es cerrada antes de que logres hacerlo, **publica una buena pregunta-autorespuesta**.

Comment: Correcto. Es importante que el nuevo usuario _(o el usuario que sea)_ entienda que su pregunta y/o respuesta se remueve del sitio **porque no cumple con la calidad del sitio. no es nada personal**.

Answer (score 0):

> 1º porque se trata de un usuario reciente en esSO,

Que sea de un usuario nuevo no significa que el listón de calidad sea más bajo. Debemos votar por el contenido, no por el usuario.
Lo que sí significa (aunque esto es discutible y es mi opinión) es que es recomendable darle un tiempo de gracia. No cerrarla, no votarle negativo y ponerle unos comentarios explicando cómo tiene que mejorarla. Si pasado un tiempo la pregunta sigue siendo de mala calidad entonces hay que cerrarla y/o votar negativo según corresponda.

> 2º porque es una pregunta que puede dar lugar a una respuesta
>   interesante, rica que más de un usuario necesitará,

Este es un muy buen motivo para mantener una pregunta abierta. Hay muchas preguntas que son interesantes y que en mi opinión sería bueno tener en el sitio pero que se pueden formular en una línea y sin trabajo de investigación.
Pero el trabajo de investigación es parte de los requisitos de una pregunta. Al menos tal y como está ahora el sitio. ¿Es esto bueno para el sitio? Esto es un tema que merece una reflexión aparte.

Algo que siempre se puede hacer es editarla para elevarla a los estandares de una buena pregunta. Aunque no sea tu pregunta. Le pones un comentario explicando por qué la has editado. Si al usuario original no le gusta siempre puede revertirla.

> 3º porque preguntas similares han tenido muy buena aceptación en enSO:
>   Veamos exactamente la misma pregunta en enSO:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database

Esto es un arma de doble filo.
Por un lado si en enSO la aceptan algo de bueno tendrá la pregunta.
Por otro lado en enSO también cometieron algunos errores. Bueno sería no repetirlos.
Y por último. Hay que tener cuidado con qué nos comparamos. El sitio enSO tiene millones de usuarios y millones de preguntas y respuestas. Casi todas las cosas fáciles que se podían preguntar están preguntadas ya. Pero eso no ocurre en nuestro sitio. El trabajo de investigación, ¿era un requisito cuando abrió enSO? ¿Es bueno para nuestro sitio?

Answer (score -3):

Pues el hecho que exista una pregunta idéntica en SOen es una buena razón para cerrar esta. En la guía [«¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?»](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) la primera recomendación es **Busca**.

Por otro lado, aprender a buscar y a encontrar respuestas es una habilidad muy útil, que no debería despreciarse. En este sentido, el comentario que deja Arie es amable, respetuoso y bastante útil, en los resultados de la búsqueda que ofrece se encuentran recursos didácticos muy completos y en formatos accesibles, como los video-tutoriales.

El formato de este sitio si es restrictivo, no te quepa la menor duda. El [«Recorrido»](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) lo dice desde el principio: *Somos ligeramente diferentes a otros sitios*. Y recomienda:

> Concéntrate en las preguntas sobre un problema real con el que te hayas encontrado. Incluye los detalles sobre lo que intentaste y lo que estás intentando hacer exactamente.

Más aún, nos dice que hay preguntas cuyas buenas respuestas son muy extensas y no funcionan bien en nuestro sitio.

Para terminar, aunque la voten en negativo, la respuesta de Ruben te da la clave para cuando veas una pregunta que consideres que puede aportar valor a la documentación especializada en nuestro idioma.

Comment: "el hecho que exista una pregunta idéntica en SOen es una buena razón para cerrar esta". No estoy de acuerdo con esto por dos cosas: 1) El contenido en SOen está en inglés y nosotros queremos brindar contenido en español. 2) Esto también significa que si tengo una duda no podría publicarla en ambos sitios porque estaría duplicando contenido.

Comment: Tienes razón @LuiggiMendoza, pero hablamos de cosas diferentes. Yo hablo en términos del usuario: no buscó información primero, le aportan contenidos valiosos. Por otro lado tu piensas en términos del sitio: _queremos contenido en español_, _no queremos contenido duplicado_. Hay que cuidar ambos aspectos: la mejora en la calidad de las preguntas atrae a más y mejores usuarios y eso lo queremos todos. ¿Tu quieres muchas preguntas malas, solo porque son contenido en español?

Comment: Voy a la frase, no a tu respuesta. Y sobre "Yo hablo en términos del usuario: no buscó información primero, le aportan contenidos valiosos". El contenido de la publicación en inglés será valioso, pero **está en inglés**. Sé que puede traducirse (y algunas ideas perderse en la traducción) pero la idea es tener contenido en español al igual que en inglés. Si no, entonces ¿cuál sería la razón de este sitio si todo lo puedes tener en inglés y si no existe allí pues se crea? Quiero un sitio SOes con calidad al igual que muchos aquí.

Comment: Ir a la frase y sacarla de contexto no siempre es adecuado.  En fin. Estoy seguro que la comunidad va por buen camino y que poco a poco iremos todos comprendiendo las restricciones y libertades que ofrece el sitio. Al final, los que queremos contenido de calidad en SOes, seguiremos aportando nuestro esfuerzo. De algo servirá.

Comment: Ok, usando la frase en la oración completa: "Pues el hecho que exista una pregunta idéntica en SOen es una buena razón para cerrar esta. En la guía «¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?» la primera recomendación es **Busca**". Pero este resultado de SOen saldrá si busco en inglés, no en español. Y a eso me centro.

Comment: Ok. Termines con esto: Tienes razón. Estoy equvocado. No debí haber escrito esa respuesta. Me arrepiento de ello. No la borro porque es evidencia de mis errores de juicio. No puedo agregar nada mas.